# Quickest way to pick up Joomla?

Tags: joomla

What is the quicket way to pick up Joomla? Books, training etc? We want to train 10 Mid-to-Senior level Java developers in Joomla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If u are trying to save time, dont start with official joomla documentation. Go to http://www.scribd.com/search?cat=redesign&q=joomla and read some short basic tutorials for a basic understanding. After that, the best approach is to install Joomla on local machine and play around for few hours, installing/modifying modules, components, installing templates and etc. Practice and only practice makes learning efficient. After that, when you will want to go deeper into specific topics, start reading more advanced documentations, forums, try to understand Joomla from the code behind. You may also use video tutorials for a basic understanding. Any developers won't have problems learning Joomla,as it's has fast learning curve.

Answer (score 3):

a good source of video tutorials is [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/)

Answer (score 2):

For backend development, I like taking the core components and examining them.

Answer (score 2):

## Joomla Component, Module, Plugins Development Video Tutorial Playlists

### Joomla 2.5 Custom Plugin Development

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7kkxuLFYIDPI3OmqbpQ05--24cAfJa2y

### Joomla 2.5 Custom Component Development

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7kkxuLFYIDOrj395REpd0golrCV7XLcY

### Joomla 2.5 Custom Module Development

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7kkxuLFYIDMUAfxq1aT-SkE3DW8N5IUk

### Joomla Miscellaneous Video Tutorials

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7kkxuLFYIDMGYYo7B1oDNSFluBiOpRx8

### JMM Joomla Mysql Manager Extension

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7kkxuLFYIDOroSTgEskA1Gr8CW13O0u3

Answer (score 1):

I find that I pick up new a framework fastest by reading tutorials and watching video screencast.

http://www.joomlatutorials.com

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.joomla.org has a ton of info. Im not sure what you are looking for but there are tutorials and documentation for all aspects (webmaster, programmer, etc). Here are some other good resources...

Great beginner tuts
http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/

Beginner to advanced
http://www.youjoomla.com/youjoomla-blog/joomla-tutorials.html

Create custom extensions
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component
http://www.techguywebsolutions.com/create-a-custom-joomla-2.5-module.html
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvx_tN_mcss